# Using Arabic labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, text, arabic

In QGIS 3.30 I am trying to render labels in Arabic. When I turn on the labels, the Arabic text appears mirrored compared to how it is correctly written in the attribute table.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I can't find the option to mirror the text, and I'm unable to make it work through HTML formatting.

[image]

The placement setting of the labels is set to "parallel", I know that there is an issue with the "curved" placement but this is not the case
[image]

Comment: Can you please show your setting, especially the placement ?

Comment: Hi Taras, yes, the placement is set to parallel

Comment: In my case, using parallel labeling work correct, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYSKD.png When I change to curved, I get the same effect as you. No idea what went wrong in your case. You should provide more details.

Comment: Thanks, Babel. I don't understand why I have this issue. I think it could be related to the OS (Win11) settings, but I'm not sure which option I should check. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea 
Not sure which one it was back then, normally I use the latest version, so must have been 3.30 back then, I guess.

Comment: @Babel, which QGIS version are you using?

Federico, there is an open issue report at github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54098 about this issue. May you please add a comment there with all the info about you system an the QGIS version used ad a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Layer Properties -> Label and open the Automated Placement Engine

[image]

2. Set the "Text rendering" option to: "Always Render Labels as Text"

[image]

Result:

[image]

If the "Text rendering" option is set to "Always Render Labels as Paths", then the labels are incorrectly displayed:

[image]

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain how to open the "Automated Placement Engine" dialog window and to also display the incorrect label placement (since it it not self-evident from the screenshot available in the Question.